# What does this sign mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to figure out:

$$\left[\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\right]_B$$

But I don't understand what the small B down there means.

So, what does the small B down there mean? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us some context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hint:it mean write this matrix according to this base(B)

Comment: you should see example in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector

Comment: More precisely: _interpret_ the matrix as giving a linear operator expressed with respect to the basis $B$.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that notation to indicate that this is the coordinate matrix of a linear transformation written with respect to the basis $B$ (used both on the input and output vector spaces).